# Add required field to VA02 for certain document types via User Exit

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I've never customized user exits before. I believe I found the correct one (Program SAPMV45A; USEREXIT_SAVE_DOCUMENT_PREPARE).

I'm not sure how to call out screen fields and check them for certain values, or how to make a screen field required using ABAP.

Basically I need this:

If VBAK-AUART = CR, CRQ, RE and If VBAK-AUGRU = 145 or 160, then VBAK-SUMBI = required

Comment: there must be *vbak structure for screen elements. Did you check it ?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how

Comment: Well, you can debug SAPMV45A exit and check the *vbak structure, same as vbak.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help!